# CSS perspective shape border

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have a trapezoid, made with CSS. The issue I'm having is with the line thickness of the bottom line. I've tried adding a solid border around the shape, but the bottom line is still a few pixels thinner.

Here's the fiddle showing the trapezoid: http://jsfiddle.net/d7fuaur1/

```
.trap { 
    width: 436px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    left: 100px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:25px; 
    padding-bottom:25px;
    top: 20px;
}

.trap:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow:0 0 0px 4px #000;
    top: -4%; bottom: -11%; left: -3%; right: -3%;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(-30deg);
    transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(-30deg);
}
```

What can I do to get the border thickness the same all around?

Comment: Well... perspective projection makes object that are further away appear smaller than the ones that are closer to the observer.

Comment: @Cicada Ah, yeah that makes sense. So I guess there is no fix? Is there some better code I could use to make a trapezoid like the one in my jsfiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest, I'm not exactly sure how this worked

In `.trap:before`

Change

```
box-shadow:0 0 0px 4px #000;
```

to

```
box-shadow:0 1px 0px 4px #000;
```

I just added 1px to your v-shadow field.

[EDIT] Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7fuaur1/2/) for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `border: <size> solid <color>` to .trap:before

```
  .trap:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 2px;
      box-shadow:0 0 0px 4px #000;
      top: -4%; bottom: -11%; left: -3%; right: -3%;
      z-index: ;
     -webkit-transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(-30deg);
      transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(-30deg);
      border: 5px solid black;
    }
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7fuaur1/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to make the border the same thickness around the whole shape. As you can see the bottom line is still quite a bit thinner than the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css  (and check the codepen demo : http://codepen.io/ChrisPlz/pen/vjkeq)

```
div {
  border-top:80px solid #C1C1C1;
  border-left:45px solid transparent;
  border-right:45px solid transparent;
  padding:0 8px 0 0;
  height:0;
  width:120px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2em auto;
  &:before {
    border-top:90px solid #000;
    border-left:50px solid transparent;
    border-right:50px solid transparent;
    padding:0 8px 0 0;
    height:0;
    width:130px; 
    position: absolute;
    top: -85px;
    left: -55px;
    content: "";
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```